# Kend UI template for Menu

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, kendo-menu

I'm creating a Razor page using ASP.NET Core 2.0. I'm creating a menu using the Kendo UI Menu control.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="treeview">
        @(
            Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("kendomainmenu")
                .BindTo((IEnumerable<MenuItem>)ViewData[SessionConstants.ViewKendoMainMenu])
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

The data is coming from a backend service which then populates the Menu control with data. All works well.

I want to use a template to customise how each menu item will display.

Here is the template (defined on the same page as the menu control).

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>#:Text#</p>
</script>
```

And here is the how the template is bound to the Menu control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kendomainmenu").kendoMenu({
      template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
    });
  });
</script>
```

I would be expecting to the word "hello" above each menu item (just to test if the template is being picked up). Inspecting with the F12 developer tools suggests also that the template is not being picked up.

How do I use a template with a KendoUI menu control. I've looked through the docs and examples but can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no `template` in the menu [configuration](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu#configuration). See [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/images) how they add images to the menu items, with a image property and not a template. Also, in that demo page, there is no template page. It's is wierd tho. I think you might need to create the html and initialize the widget over it to achieve what you need.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Can you explain what you mean - "I think you might need to create the html and initialize the widget over it to achieve what you need"

Comment: I mean like [this](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/index), you can see that the html is all ploted prior the initialization, instead of creating it with json or something like.